# Should I use function-based exports/imports or classes?

Tags: functional-programming, node.js, class-design

What would make more sense, to use functions for exports/imports:

```
// globals/helpers.js
exports.fnOne = () => {}

// features/user.js
const {fnOne} = require()
```

Or class-based approach with static methods?

Same question goes for features development. Should I create functions within `user.js` and export/import them in my service layer, or should I create user class with methods and use that?

I never coded with OOP before and I know that it's only syntactical sugar in JS.

Please share performance details or perhaps some caveats that I will probably encounter going with one or another direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Exports/imports make more sense IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is a bit special, and some advice from other languages doesn't generalize. For example, static methods are pretty rare in JavaScript. Objects are used very differently to other languages, because you can just create objects in an ad-hoc manner without having to define a class first. You don't have to use JavaScript in an OOP manner.

The general rule of thumb (for any language) is to do the simplest thing that works. If you want a function, use a function – turning it into a static method and wrapping a class around it probably doesn't solve any problem.

There is not going to be a big performance difference either way. Usually, simple code is also performant code. There is definitely no performance penalty for using plain functions.

Comment: "JavaScript is a bit special" free functions were the norm before Java